# Ubuntu on MacBook won't boot

Tags: boot, usb, macbook

I want to run Ubuntu 14 from a USB flash drive as alternative system on my MacBook Mid 2007 computer...
I installed Ubuntu from the LiveDVD 14.04 LTS, and it completed successfully into a 32GB USB 3.0 flash drive! (Kingstone DataTraveler Ultimate)

My problem is that when rebooting the system, the USB flash drive is not recognized as a boot device and therefor the system boots into Max OSX as if there was nothing else attached...

When I login it reports that "**the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer**"!

What am I missing?

Comment: Try holding the option key while booting.